# Error when Deploying Commerce Engine

Tags: sitecore-commerce-server

I am setting Sitecore Commerce on my machine.
At the Deploy Commerce Engine stage [Link](http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreCommerce/DeploymentGuide/en-us/index.html%23Concepts/c_SC_Deploy_Commerce_Engine.html) . 
On the dotnet restore command, I am getting this error where it says AspNetCore.OData is not compatible.

*Errors in C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine\project.json
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 6.0.0-alpha1-rtm-171013 is not compatible with net452 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData
6.0.0-alpha1-rtm-171013 supports: net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.*

I checked in the gobal.json in Sitecore.Commerce.SDK and the Core version matches the Dotnet SDK version  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"

I have .net 4.5,4.6.1 and 4.6.2 installed on my machine.

Adding the cmd file log for refrence

C:\Program Files (x86)\Commerce Server 11\Tools>cd C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301

C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301>dotnet restore

log  : Restoring packages for C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301\PluginSamples\Plugin.Sample.Habitat\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301\PluginSamples\Plugin.Sample.Payments.Braintree\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301\Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.AdventureWorks\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine\project.json...

log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301\PluginSamples\Plugin.Sample.Habitat\project.lock.json
log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:Users\xxxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301\PluginSamples\Plugin.Sample.Payments.Braintree\project.lock.json

log  : C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301\PluginSamples\Plugin.Sample.Habitat\project.json
log  : Restore completed in 11844ms.

log  : C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301\PluginSamples\Plugin.Sample.Payments.Braintree\project.json
log  : Restore completed in 11856ms.

log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301\Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.AdventureWorks\project.lock.json
log  : C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301\Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.AdventureWorks\project.json
log  : Restore completed in 11388ms.

error: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 6.0.0-alpha1-rtm-171013 is not compatible with net452 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2). 
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 6.0.0-alpha1-rtm-171013 supports: net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.
log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine\project.lock.json
log  : C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine\project.json
log  : Restore failed in 22890ms.

Errors in C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\SitecoreCommerce8.2.1_1.0.20\Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine\project.json
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 6.0.0-alpha1-rtm-171013 is not compatible with net452 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2). 
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData6.0.0-alpha1-rtm-171013 supports: net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project.json file on Sitecore.Commerce.SDK.1.0.2301\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine has dependencies set like this:

"Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData":  "6.0.0-alpha1-rtm-*"

Unfortunately, the latest version (171013) seems to require a higher version of .NET

edit the file and make specify a lower version

"Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData":  "6.0.0-alpha1-rtm-121216"